# Android MediaPlayer fails to buffer long audio

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have an android app in playstore, which plays audio asynchronously using CDN url. When it starts playing an audio, it shows buffering progress and seek progress.

It performs fine with short audio files. But for long audio files it stops buffering in a certain minute. This buffering progress varies in device to device. I observed, in a specific device, if an audio can buffer till 30 min, in another it might be 20 min and always stops buffering in the same minute for that audio. If I seek to the unbuffered area, audio doesn't play not even buffer newly.

Here is the example

[image: Stops buffering the a point]

In the example-

- File size: 37.02MB, Duration: ~54 min, Buffered: 25 - 30 min
- Device's memory specification: RAM: 8GB, Storage: 128GB

I guess when an audio is buffered and cached in local storage, the allocated storage or RAM exceeds. If this is the issue, is there any way to clear memory which part was already played and re initiate buffering for rest of the part?

To be mentioned, I implemented the controller by myself instead of using `MediaController` and I've initiated and used the `MediaPlayer` object inside the `Fragment` instead of `Service`.